# How to cache images from url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 application that displays images from another PHP application that is located on a remote server.

I would like to know what is the best solution to cache the images from the remote server on my local Laravel App.

Please note that it's *almost impossible* to copy/past the entire images directory from the remote server, since there are more than 150k images that are regurlary updated (every minutes) and there is a database correlation too (filename with column value in database).

I was about to use `Rsync` to sync the two directories (distant with local), but I also need to resize images before displaying them and organize the images subdirectories in a different way than it is on the remote server.

First I have installed the [Intervention Image Class](http://image.intervention.io/) package on Laravel and I have created a `Route`:

```
Route::get('photos/item/{size}/{reference}/{photo}', 'ImgController@showImg');
```

And in the `ImgController`:

```
public function showImg( $size, $reference, $photo )
{
    switch ( $size ) {
       case '300x225':
          $jpg = Image::make( 'http://myremoteapp.com/uploads/' . $reference . '/' . $photo )->resize( 300, 225 )->response( 'jpg' );
       break;
    }
    return $jpg;
}
```

This works but it doesn't keep the images in the browser's cache and it also creates a performance issue, since the images have to be downloaded and resized every time the page is opened.

I have heard about the [Intervention Image Cache](https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache) but I am not sure if it works with images taken from URLs.

Any advice and suggestions on how to resolve this in a proper way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cache route as:

```
Route::filter('cache', function($route, $request, $response = null) {
    $key = 'route-' . safe_title(URL::full());
    if( is_null($response) && Cache::has($key) ) {
        return Cache::get($key);
    } elseif( !is_null($response) && !Cache::has($key) ) {
        // Code this here
        Cache::put($key, $response->getContent(), 30);
    }
});

    Route::group(array( 'before' => 'cache', 'after' => 'cache' ), function() {
    Route::get('photos/item/{size}/{reference}/{photo}', 'ImgController@showImg');
});
```

attention :
Route::filter() was wiped away from Laravel since > 5.0